# Data not saving to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I'm currently trying upload images to a database by using Mutler and GridFS - which is successful. But I'm also trying to create a caption via the same form, but saving the data into a different schema. My problem is that on the POST route, it's not saving the data to the `Posts` schema - but no errors are being returned - but as well as that, I'm not being redirected the index page.

**model.js schema for caption data**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    caption: {
        type: String,
    },
    fileID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'fs' //created by multer gridfs storage
    }
});

const Posts = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema);
module.exports = { Posts };
```

**app.js**

```
// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/grid-fs";

// Mongo connection
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

// Mongoose Schema
const { Posts } = require('./models/model');

// Init gfs
let gfs;

connection.once("open", () => {
    // Init stream
    gfs = Grid(connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection("uploads");
})

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: mongoURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: "uploads"
                };
                resolve(fileInfo);
            });
        });
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
        // Check if files exist
        if (!files || files.length === 0) {
            res.render("index", {files: false})
        } else {
            files.map(file => {
                if(file.contentType === "image/jpeg" || file.contentType === "image/png") {
                    file.isImage = true;
                } else {
                    file.isImate = false;
                }
            });
            res.render('index', {files: files})
        }
    });
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    const post = new Posts({
        caption: req.body.caption,
        fileID: req.file.id
    });
    console.log(req.body.caption)
    console.log(req.file.id)
    console.log(post)
    post.save().then( result => {
        res.redirect('/');
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("Unable to save data");
    });
});
```

I refresh the page the image is pushed to the frontend, but when I check the database the caption content is missing - no schema is there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this db.getCollectionNames() and check if your collection is there or not if it doesnot exists

try this

```
Posts.create({
    caption: req.body.caption,
    fileID: req.file.id
}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) res.status(400).send("Unable to save");
    else {
        res.redirect("/")
    }
})
```

Comment: Page loading icon is on a continuous loop